# Display unique column when not all values are distinct

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
Name Status Contact EpisodeNumber
AA   C      E       1
AA   C      F       1
AA   C      G       1
AA   D      H       1
BB   D      I       2
CC   C      J       3
DD   C      K       4
```

---

If D is present on any of the 'status' column of the given Names i don't want to see them. each 'contact' is different which is fine, i need to make sure the EpisodeNumber is the same. What happens is everytime "Status" is changed it creates a new row for that name with the contact that changed it so i can't do a simple select * where status != 'D' because it will show me the other statuses for that given episodenumber. We are running SQL server 2008 R2 with sql management studio version 10.50.6560.0 and report builder 3.0

```
Name Status Contact EpisodeNumber
CC   C      J       3
DD   C      K       4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think `NOT EXISTS` should work.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
    NAME VARCHAR(30)
    ,STATUS VARCHAR(5)
    ,Contact VARCHAR(5)
    ,EpisodeNumber INT
    );
INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
    ('AA', 'C', 'E', 1),
    ('AA', 'C', 'F', 1),
    ('AA', 'C', 'G', 1),
    ('AA', 'D', 'H', 1),
    ('BB', 'D', 'I', 2),
    ('CC', 'C', 'J', 3),
    ('DD', 'C', 'K', 4)
;
SELECT *
FROM @T t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM @T
        WHERE NAME = t.NAME
            AND EpisodeNumber = t.EpisodeNumber
            AND STATUS = 'D'
        );
```

---

```
| NAME | STATUS | Contact | EpisodeNumber |
|------|--------|---------|---------------|
| CC   | C      | J       | 3             |
| DD   | C      | K       | 4             |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `IN` clause

```
select * 
from YourTable
where [Name] not in (select [Name] from YourTable where [Status] = 'D')
```